# Excel file marked corrupt because of alternate data stream

Tags: microsoft-excel

This Excel file, [promoImportTemplate.xls](http://admin.pressero.com/images/promoImportTemplate.xls), is a perfectly valid Excel file when opened from its source.  When downloaded from my IIS server at the URL above, using either curl, Firefox, Chrome, or IE, the saved file has exactly the same file size and MD5:

```
C:\Users\rpresser\Downloads>md5sum p*xls
1ec492aef69bd9cf2b784003167addbb *promoImportTemplate - Chrome download.xls
1ec492aef69bd9cf2b784003167addbb *promoImportTemplate - curl.xls
1ec492aef69bd9cf2b784003167addbb *promoImportTemplate - original.xls
```

When downloaded using a browser, there is an [Alternate Data Stream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_streams_.28ADS.29) that marks the file as having come from the Internet Zone. This is normal and expected.  However, it makes Excel claim the file is corrupt. There are *no* other differences between the working file and the "corrupt" file. The MD5 is the same, and the files are all marked read-only to prevent Excel from changing an internal timestamp. See [this video](http://screencast.com/t/MM78wzYCsiD) for a demonstration.

If I delete the ADS using the [Streams](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897440.aspx) utility, then the downloaded file opens normally. (Not in video, sorry. I thought of that later.)

Is there even a possible explanation for this weird behavior?

Comment: So should I get the corrupt version from your link?  The file downloaded in Chrome and opened just fine (it did add the additional stream and it was opened in protected mode).  I am using Excel 2013.

Comment: If I download from my link using Chrome, Firefox or IE, it adds the stream, and then Excel 2013 reports that the file is corrupt.  If I download using curl, it does not add the stream, and the file opens normally. I too am using Excel 2013, on Windows 8.1 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I would think the explanation might be that the file had some macros running on opening which would make the file work, and when it has the ADS added it was opened in Protected Mode and the macros were not able to run.

Comment: That's a nice thought but incorrect. Nobody in the company that I worked at in 2014 was using macros in their Excel files. This problem disappeared later in 2014, so I have to assume that it was an Excel 2013 bug that got fixed.